# Fetch Data From MS SQL DB Using Ajax Auto Complete extender

Tags: web-services, connection-string

I have an .aspx page that calls the .asmx web method to extract data from the MS SQL DB. I have tested the result without the connectionstring and it works.

I think my problem is with my connection string within the web.config, but i am not sure how to set it up.  When i try to run the search with the SQL command i either get 500 server error or just nothing. Can someone please provide some advise?

**partial web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myConn" connectionString="Data Source=D:\\root\\Database\\; Initial Catalog=myData.mdb;Integrated Security=sspi;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**Web Method**

```
Dim customers As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

Dim conn As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConn").ConnectionString
Dim cmd As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT col1, col2 from myTable where" &
   " , like @SearchText + '%'"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText)
cmd.Connection = conn
conn.Open()

Dim sdr As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
While sdr.Read
    Dim item As String = AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem(sdr("col1").ToString, sdr("col2").ToString)
    customers.Add(item)
End While

conn.Close()

Return customers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, since i was trying to connection to an Access database, I was suppose to use OleDB connection instead of SqlClient.

So I replaced all Sqlclient with OldDb and it promptly solved the problem. So it turns out, it is very important to know which database type you are connecting to before you try to make that connection.